# Sum Hex Values using Python to get CheckSum

Tags: python, python-2.7

My question maybe is simple but i'm not good with bytes/hex operations. I need to do a checksum from a Serial Port data with this Values:

55 55 3A 0B 47 09 3E 08 FF 0F 93

The last value 93 is the sum value but i don't know how to do this.
55 + 55 + 3A + 0B + 47 + 09 + 3E + 08 + FF + 0F = 93

Comment: How do you receive the data? Are these strings? ints?

Comment: I receive the data in strings

Answer (score 1):

Convert the raw bytestring into a sequence of numbers, then add all but the last number, mask to byte-length, and compare the result with the last number in the sequence.

```
>>> data = bytearray('\x55\x55\x3a\x0b\x47\x09\x3e\x08\xff\x0f\x93')
>>> sum(data[:-1]) & 0xff == data[-1]
True
```

Comment: Little explanation will make it a great answer. BTW + 1 from my side